# How to shorten the usage of methods in C#?

Tags: c#, methods

I have many string variables like this;

```
string x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8;
```

Is it possible to shorten this code

```
method(x1);
method(x2);
method(x3);
method(x4);
method(x5);
method(x6);
method(x7);
method(x8);
```

so I can use something like this instead (This below doesn't work):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
{
    method("x" + i);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have all those variables in the first place? It sounds like you should be using a list.

Comment: You could use reflection, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: throw all the x variables in a list, and iterate through that list

Comment: You are passing a string literal to the `method` variable. You aren't actually giving it the value of the variable with the same name as the string you're passing in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an array for all these strings:

```
string[] data = new []
{
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
    "string4",
    x1,
    x2,
    x3,
    x4
};

foreach(var item in data)
{
    method(item);
}
```

With arrays it is the same, just have a collection of arrays:

```
var data = new List<string[]>
{
    new [] {"1","2","3"},
    new [] {"a","b","c"},
};

foreach(var item in data)
{
    method2(item); //notice that this method must get as a parameter a string[]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same for Arrays? E.g.

    string[] x1;
    string[] x2;

and then

    method(x1);
    method(x2);

Comment: @Liquid Core - not really but would like to understand what you are referring too :) this code is for this specific question only

Answer (score 1):

The other answers show how to loop through the values and call the method for each value. An alternative if you can rewrite the method is to let it accept multiple parameters.

```
static void YourMethod(params string[] values)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        // Do your work
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
YourMethod(x1, x2, x3, x4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of Gilad you can use List and ForEach:

```
var data = new List<string>
{
    "string1",
    "string2",
    "string3",
    "string4",
    x1,
    x2,
    x3,
    x4
};

data.ForEach(x => method(x));
```

or even shorter:

```
data.ForEach(method);
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `.ForEach` is a method of `List<T>` (and just a small correction, it isn't part of linq. just a method of List)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aforementioned foreach loops, or in a way that looks more clean to me, use an [Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for the object type you're using. This is good expecially if you're using that method a lot but it will work anyway.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] test = { 1, 12, 13, 11, 31, 41, 21};
        test.CycleArray();
    }
    public static void CycleArray(this int[] myArr)
    {
        if (myArr.Length > 0)
            foreach (int x in myArr)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

Then you can call the method on any object of that type without having to write anymore code.

doing

```
test.CycleArray();
```

everytime you get an object of type int[] will work without additional code.

That is the way if you're not willing to use LINQ.  In that last case

```
MyArray.ForEach(x => x+="i");
```

Will do the same in a single line, assumed that your code isn't working, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dictionary of string and action something like below

```
 Dictionary<string, Action<string>> _mapOfMethods = new Dictionary<string,Action<string>> { { "TestString1", Method1 }, {"TestString2", Method2 }};
```

And then you could use a foreach statement like below

```
        foreach (var item in _mapOfMethods)
        {
            item.Value(item.Key);
        }
```